# Не получается найти элемент на странице

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Необходимо ввести данные для авторизации в поле "Имя пользователя" и "Пароль" на странице. В инструменте разработчика браузера Firefox элемент страницы выглядит так:

[image: элемент на странице]

```
<input class="fld-input" type="text" name="login" maxlength="10">
```

Скопированный XPath выглядит так:

```
/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input
```

Пытаюсь найти элемент при помощи find_element_by_xpath:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("адрес_сайта")
time.sleep(5)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
elem.send_keys("test")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Выдается ошибка "NoSuchElementException":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/panchous/PycharmProjects/work_web/venv/web.py", line 8, in <module>
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
  File "C:\Users\panchous\PycharmProjects\work_web\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\panchous\PycharmProjects\work_web\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\panchous\PycharmProjects\work_web\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\panchous\PycharmProjects\work_web\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/center/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input
```

При помощи driver.find_element_by_name:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
```

Итог:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="login"]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти указанный элемент.

Comment: А почему именно `selenium`. Какова конечная цель кода?

Comment: Конечная цель - авторизоваться на сайте и скачать необходимые данные в текстовом формате. Я новичок в данной сфере, поэтому, что первое нашел, тем и попытался безуспешно воспользоваться.

Comment: ИМХО лучше для данной цели использовать `requests`. А ссылочку на сайт можно? Так сказать для проведения полевых испытаний

Comment: Сайт корпоративный, доступа извне нет :(

Comment: Спасибо за совет, через requests получилось.